# Pass a message from ServiceActivator to new InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have implemented `Spring (boot) integration`, i have a `InboundChannelAdapter` and this method sending a web request via RestTemplate, and pass result to Splitter, Filter, And finally to a ServiceActivator, ServiceActivator saving the data into database.
I want to pass message to a new "`InboundChannelAdapter`" in order to some additional process on the message after saving data into database,  What should i do in order to implement this?
Is my solution right solution?

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel1", poller = @Poller("downloadTrigger"))
public ResponseEntity<AppsItemParser[]> download()
{
    String url = config.getUrl();
    // Call a rest webservice
    return responseEntity;
}

@Splitter(inputChannel = "channel1", outputChannel = "channel2")
public List<AppsItemParser> scrape(ResponseEntity<AppsItemParser[]> payload)
{
    return new ArrayList<AppsItemParser>(Arrays.asList(payload.getBody()));
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "channel2", outputChannel = "channel3")
public App convert(AppsItemParser payload)
{
    App app = new App();
    app.setAddDate(payload.getAddDate());
    app.setSize(payload.getSize());

    return app;
}

@Filter(inputChannel = "channel3", outputChannel = "channel4")
public boolean filter(App app)
{
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<App>> violations = validator.validate(app);
    if (violations != null && !violations.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel4")
    public void save(App app)
    {
        appRepository.save(app);
        //Send message to another spring integration flow
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inbound channel adapters define the start of a flow; they do not receive messages from other components; instead, have your service return a result...

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel4", outputChannel="next")
public App save(App app)
{
    appRepository.save(app);
    return app;
}
```

or

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel4", outputChannel="next")
public SomeResult save(App app)
{
    appRepository.save(app);
    return new SomeResult(...);
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to chat you regarding this topic?

Comment: I want to send App POJO to a new channel from above ServiceActivator, in the new channel i want to connect to a another External Http Server and pass the payload to transformer and filter it and then save it.

Comment: What I showed you will do exactly that, the App will be sent to the channel `next`; you can add whatever components you want after that.